# Transparent status bar swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, transparency, statusbar

I have an app where the navigation bar is translucent however the status bar still has a white background and black text.

Like here:

[image]

I want the status bar to be transparent and the text in the status bar to be white.

How can I achieve this with Swift on iOS 15?

Answer (score 0):

In your UIViewController add:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent // FOR WHITE STATUS BAR TEXT COLOR OR .darkContent FOR BLACK
}
```

For set statusBar backgroundColor use this:

```
 let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .filter {$0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
            .map {$0 as? UIWindowScene }
            .compactMap { $0 }
            .first?.windows
            .filter({ $0.isKeyWindow }).first
 let statusBar = UIView(frame: keyWindow?
            .windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame ?? CGRect.zero)
 statusBar.backgroundColor = .clear
 keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBar)
```

Comment: Your code gives me warnings saying: 'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes

Comment: @es1, fix this in my answer

Comment: I fixed it. Now I am getting a black background for the status bar. But I want a transparent background.

Comment: Sorry) Use clear color for this

Comment: I used clear but then it goes back to a white background for the status bar.

Comment: Itself after some time or when switching between controllers?

Comment: Itself. Instantly.

Comment: Strange, maybe it has something to do with the structure of your application. I tested the code on my test application, it worked for me with no return for white color.
I'm added statusBar settings in viewDidAppear